# In my android studio , i dont have string.xml tab/file , how to create one and define strings in that?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

here is the screenshot of my android studio, i tried to manually build string.xml but it shows rendering and resource problems

[image]

Comment: What errors do you see? Where did you try to make it?

Comment: it was in my values folder ..i tried to run.. it worked now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strings.xml is located in values folder